# Is there a way to install apk from com.android.filemanager programmatically

Tags: android

Using 'adb install xx.apk' will get a popup window requires password on manufacture from oppo and vivo, however if push the apk file to /sdcard then go to filemangeer and tap the apk just pushed, no password is required.
I wonder if there is a way to do this via another apk?

```
            String sdcardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            final String apkSavePath = sdcardRoot + "/510.apk";
            File apkFile = new File(apkSavePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (!apkFile.exists()) {
                return;
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                try {
                    String ss = "com.xunmeng.pinduoduo" + ".provider";
                    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), ss, apkFile);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

This one doesnt work since it called the file installation from the apk I build rather than  com.android.filemanger.
Is there a way to run the file installation from com.android.filemanger?

Comment: Two ways to reach ur point : 1. make ur application able to install apks by enable "install unknown source app " in settings . 2. send intent to filemanager.

Comment: @cowboi-peng I replace intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); with intent.setAction("com.android.filemanager/com.android.filemanager.FileManagerListActivity"); then get this error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.filemanager/com.android.filemanager.FileManagerListActivity dat=content://com.xunmeng.pinduoduo.provider/external_storage_root/510.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000001 }

Comment: Add these:                        intent.setPackage("com.android.filemanager");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE); then got error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=con